# Unicode vector over a character string

Tags: unicode, pyqt5, python-3.5

I'm using Python 3.5, PyQT5 and I need to print a character with a vector above it. 
I know I have to use a Unicode codepoint, and I tried the following instruction :

```
    myLabel = QLabel(b"\U+20D6".encode('utf-16','ignore')
```

Nothing worked. It does not work with any type of encoding (utf-8, utf-16, ecc.).
My goal is to put an arrow above a character, according to the tutorial found on the web I have to use unicode b"\U+20D6" codepoint.
Do you know right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried with pyqt but testing in IDLE with python 3.5 `"\u20d6"` gives the excepted string, so I guess `QLabel("\u20d6")` should work

Comment: @Neitsa Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work. The following error persistring: _SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodcceescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape_

Comment: Weird, I have a correct output on python 3.5 and python 3.4.2 on IDLE: `>>> "\u20d6" '⃖' `